# To retrieve the contents of file based on their latest modified date

Tags: powershell

I wanted to retrieve contents of file based on latest time stamp. I tried below code snippet but the outcome was not as expected.

```
    if(Get-Content $data)
    {

            $result = @()
             $r = Get-ChildItem $data| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime }
                for($i = ($data.Count -1); $i -ge 0; $i--) 
                {
                    $result += $data[$i]
                    if ($data[$i] -like $r) 
                    { 
                        break
                    }
                }
            [array]::Reverse($result)
            $result 

    }
```

The a.txt file has the contents in the below format

```
Fri 09/27/2019 15:31:03.38 Windows driver installed
Fri 09/27/2019 15:31:03.47 Paint updated
Fri 09/27/2019 15:31:19.07 Folders are updated 
Fri 09/27/2019 15:31:19.13 Necessary files are not found 
Thu 12/05/2019 15:14:57.75 Folders are updated 
Thu 12/05/2019 15:14:58.35 Necessary files are not found 
Thu 12/05/2019 15:14:58.42 Need to install game services
Thu 12/05/2019 15:14:58.46 Error in services
Thu 12/05/2019 15:15:02.61 Aborting
```

How can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing and poorly framed question, but if I understand this correctly, you are trying to get the `lastwritetime` of the file and looking of the entry in the file that corresponds to that time. Correct?

The problem I see is that, the value in `$r` is incorrect. The `for` table wont work because u are not using the file content but the file name instead.  Assuming `$data` is the filename, it should be:

```
$filecontent = Get-Content $data

$result = @()
$r = ((Get-ChildItem $data).LastWriteTime).ToString("ddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ff")

Foreach ($line in $filecontent)
{
    if ($line -match $r)
    {
        $result += $line
    }
}
$result
```